# Deduce variadic args and return type from functor template parameter (MSVC-specific)

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, visual-studio-2012

The function `invoke` in the following code is a simple wrapper for invoking another function / functor / lambda, such that `invoke(f,args...)` equals `f(args...)`. (The reason behind this is to also have overloads for member functions, allowing a generalized syntax for both usages.)

This implementation works in g++:

```
template <class Fn, class ...Args>
auto invoke(Fn f, Args ...args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
    return f(args...);
}

int y = invoke([](int x){ return x+1; }, 42);   // y = 43
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/GR4Joh)

However, MSVC 2012 (Nov CTP) complains:

```
Error: C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type invoke(Fn,Args...)'
With the following template arguments:
'main::<lambda_687537b292ffb7afcfd8f8fc292d6e73>'
'int'
```

(Note that the `int` in the error message comes from the `42` being passed to `invoke`, not from the lambda's argument. I checked this by passing something different to `invoke`.)

How can I fix this to work with MSVC 2012 (Nov CTP)?

Things I tried:

- When I change the variadic template arguments to a single argument (but still a template argument, i.e. remove all `...` in the code above), the code compiles. But I need to Support any number of arguments.
- It also compiles if I replace the trailing return type with a non-generic `int` return type. But obviously I want to support generic return types.
- The behavior doesn't change if I pass a function pointer instead of a lambda. So it isn't related to lambdas. Example error message:

  ```
  Error: C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type invoke(Fn,Args...)'
  With the following template arguments:
  'int (__cdecl *)(int)'
  'double'
  ```

Comment: Variadic templates were implemented in Visual Studio 2013. See [Support for C++11 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Comment: "`invoke(f,args...)` equals `f(args...)`". With how `invoke` is currently defined, `invoke(f, std::move(x))` will not be equivalent to `f(std::move(x))`. You need to have the arguments forwarded through the use of universal/forwarding references and `std::forward`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter They have been added in MSVC 2012 with the November CTP patch

Comment: @MarkGarcia Thanks, but I already did that, and since I get the compilation errors, I stripped the complexity down to a minimum.

Comment: CTPs are alpha-quality software. I won't be surprised if they have bugs.

Comment: @Yakk I want to use the crypto++ library which is officially supported for up to MSVC 2012 only. Not sure if it works with 2013 too, but I wanted to go the safe path.

Comment: @leemes I'd suggest that using a production quality compiler (VS2013) is safer than using an alpha-quality CTP (besides, the library is likely tested on the release version of VC2012 rather than the CTP which is more like VC2013 alpha).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your recommendation. I guess in the end we'll use GCC. The thing is, the application is using C++11 a lot, and we'd like to use a FIPS certified AES crypto library. Crypto++ provides this for MSVC 2010 builds and I hoped that in the long term they also provide a certified build for 2012 or newer. Thus I hoped 2012 is a good choice, but since the code shows even harder compilation problems (with SFINAE and stuff), I guess using MinGW and dropping the need for a certified crypto is a better choice. Maybe OpenSSL is an option in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `typename result_of<F(Args...)>::type`. (and I do mean the case: use types not values).

This does not support SFINAE under the standard, but if might work in half compliant C++11 compilers.

Also use `Args&&...` and perfect forward if your compiler does not blow up.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Seems to work (for now).